# Playing brothers the tale of two sons with 2 XBOX 360 controller

Tags: brothers-tale-of-two-sons

Can anyone tell me how I can play with two Xbox 360 control in this game ?

play one on the keyboard and the other person on the joystick it really uncomfortable .

Comment: This doesn't make sense... Have you connected another controller?

Comment: @Ben, IIRC this game has two in game characters, each controller by a side if of the controller. I believe asker intends to say they are each holding one side of the one controller, which would give each player complete control of a single character.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The game doesn't support playing with two controllers. The second controller is just listed in the menu.

Source: [Steam discussion of "Brothers - A Tale of Two Sons"](http://steamcommunity.com/app/225080/discussions/).

In [this](http://steamcommunity.com/app/225080/discussions/0/540736780988288464/) post for example there is a software recommended who is called "xpadder" as a workaround for your problem. But I don't have experience with those.